# How to add a new line to a property in pega

Tags: pega

I want to create a new line in a property which acts as a source of a connect-file. I want to add every new record in a new line. I tried `\n and \r` but they did not seem to work. Or is there some other way to add a new line for every record in the output file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using the Connect-File Method and you are referencing the property you can add "\r\n" including the quotes to add a line break. This works when the output is a csv file.

Alternatively, depending on the the file extension, you might want to explore different sources such as HTML and create the structure of the file from there.